# Установка Модулей php7

Tags: php, php7

Как установить модули bcmatch и pthreads?
Пробовал через pecl, но выдает ошибку

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43905580/5441700

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: valid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Co
mand.php on line 249
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /u
r/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Answer (score 1):

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt update
apt install php7.1-bcmath
```

Перезапути apache.

Источник [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905580/php-7-1-bcmath-not-working)